# sso session invalidation when using keycloak

Tags: keycloak, mod-auth-openidc

I am using mod_auth_openidc in front of keycloak and it works great. 
There is one scenario where I am not sure what is the best way to handle.

1, user logs in to the application ( has a token ) via mod_auth_openidc

applications use the locale stored in the access token to display language dependent content

2, user goes to keycloak account page and changes it's locale

inside keycloak the new locale is stored

3, user returns to the any of the applications

sine mod_auth_openidc cached the access tokens they still contain the stale user attributes

is there a way to force mod_auth_openidc to invalidate the all access tokens and get the a new one from keycloak ?

I tried

- ?refresh=&access_token=

and I did receive the new access token which is great. The new access token contains the right locale and user attributes.

Although the headers still contain stale data.

is this the right behaviour or is it a big in mod_open_id

anybody had any experience with this ?

ps: Also I am unable to logout now from this session

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: Hi, I can confirm this is a bug I will report it now

Comment: I'd call it a mismatch of expectations: https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc/issues/251